# Python project code editor reports "bad event type or keysym"

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

I was writing a code editor program and it gave me this error:

```
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\example\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1402, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Quote"
```

the code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import subprocess

vartitle = "(zBudText)"

def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Python Files", "*.py")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            code_editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            code_editor.insert(tk.END, file.read())

def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Python Files", "*.py")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "w") as file:
            file.write(code_editor.get(1.0, tk.END))
        messagebox.showinfo("Information", "File saved successfully.")
        window.title(os.path.basename(file_path))

def run_code():
    code = code_editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
    try:
        # Pass the -Xfrozen_modules=off argument
        process_args = ["python", "-Xfrozen_modules=off", "-c", code]

        # Set the PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION environment variable
        os.environ['PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION'] = '1'

        process = subprocess.Popen(process_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        if output:
            output_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            output_text.insert(tk.END, output.decode())
        if error:
            output_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            output_text.insert(tk.END, error.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))

def about():
    messagebox.showinfo("About this program", "Made by zbud. Written in Python 3 with PyCharm IDE")

def insert_close_parentheses(event):
    code_editor.insert(tk.INSERT, "()")
    code_editor.mark_set(tk.INSERT, f"{tk.INSERT}-1c")

def insert_close_quotes(event):
    code_editor.insert(tk.INSERT, '"')
    code_editor.mark_set(tk.INSERT, f"{tk.INSERT}-1c")

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Untitled " + vartitle)

# Create a menu bar
menu_bar = tk.Menu(window)

# Create a "File" menu
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.quit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

helpmenu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=about)

window.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Create the code editor widget
code_editor = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=80, height=20)
code_editor.pack()
code_editor.bind("(", insert_close_parentheses)  # Bind "(" to automatically insert "()".
code_editor.bind("<Double-Quote>", insert_close_quotes)  # Bind '"' to automatically insert '""'.


# Create a "Run" button
run_button = tk.Button(window, text="Run", command=run_code)
run_button.pack()

# Create the output widget
output_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=80, height=10)
output_text.pack()

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

i was expecting it to make so that when i type " it autocompletes it

Comment: Why don't you just use `'"'` instead of `"<Double-Quote>"`?